# How to share HGLOBAL with another application?

Tags: c++, winapi, shared-memory

I'm trying to understand something about `HGLOBAL`s, because I just found out that what I thought is simply wrong.

In app A I `GlobalAlloc()` data (with `GMEM_SHARE|GMEM_MOVABLE`) and place the string `"Test"` in it. Now, what can I give to another application to get to that data?

I though (wrongfully!) that `HGLOBAL`s are valid in all the processes, which is obviously wrong, because `HGLOBAL` is a `HANDLE` to the global data, and not a pointer to the global data (that's where I said "OHHHH!").

So how can I pass the `HGLOBAL` to another application?

Notice: I want to pass just a "pointer" to the data, not the data itself, like in the clipboard.

Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: You may read first about IPC on windows.

Comment: `HGLOBAL` is a hold-over from 16-bit Windows. There's nothing "global" about them any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation.  With the introduction of 32-bit processing, `GlobalAlloc()` does not actually allocate global memory anymore.

To share a memory block with another process, you could allocate the block with `GlobalAlloc()` and put it on the clipboard, then have the other process retreive it.  Or you can allocate a block of shared memory using `CreateFileMapping()` and `MapViewOfFile()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Don't be confused with `GMEM_SHARE` flag. It does not work the way you possibly supposed. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The following values are obsolete, but are provided for compatibility
>   with 16-bit Windows. They are ignored.
>
> ```
> GMEM_SHARE
> ```

[`GMEM_SHARE` flag explained by Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/02/251068.aspx):

> In 16-bit Windows, the GMEM_SHARE flag controlled whether the memory
>   should outlive the process that allocated it.

To share memory with another process/application you instead should take a look at [File Mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): [Memory-mapped files and how they work](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/khen1234/archive/2006/01/30/519483.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

(This is just a very long comment as others have already explained that Win32 takes different approach to memory sharing.)

I would say that you are reading into books (or tutorials) on Windows programming which are quite old and obsolete as Win16 is virtually dead for quite some time.

16-bit Windows (3.x) didn't have the concept of memory isolation (or virtual /flat/ address space) that 32-bit (and later) Windows versions provide. Memory there used to be divided into local (to the process) and global sections, both living in the same global address space. Descriptors like `HGLOBAL` were used to allow memory blocks to be moved around in physical memory and still accessed correctly despite their new location in the address space (after proper fixation with `LocalLock()`/`GlobalLock()`). Win32 uses pointers instead since physical memory pages can be moved without affecting their location in the virtual address space. It still provides all of the `Global*` and `Local*` API functions for compatibility reasons but they should not be used anymore and usual heap management should be used instead (e.g. `malloc()` in C or the `new` operator in C++). Also several different kind of pointers existed on Win16 in order to reflect on the several different addressing modes available on x86 - near (same segment), far (segment:offset) and huge (normalised segment:offset). You can still see things like `FARPTR` in legacy Win16 code that got ported to Win32 but they are defined to be empty strings as in flat mode only near pointers are used.

Answer (score 2):

Each process "thinks" that it owns the full memory space available on the computer.  No process can "see" the memory space of another process.  As such, normally, nothing a process stores can be seen by another process.

Because it can be necessary to pass information between processess, certain mechanisms exists to provide this functionality.

One approach is message passing; one process issues a message to another, for example over a pipe, or a socket, or by a Windows message.

Another is shared memory, where a given block of memory is made available to two or more processes, such that whatever one process writes can be seen by the others.