# Delphi: How save a pointer of a variable of an Application to be used in another Application?

Tags: arrays, delphi, pointers, pascal

In Pascal Delphi,  How save or pass a pointer of a variable of an Application to be used in another Application?

l need to access de value of a variable of the type double and a array of double in another application.

initially when I save in hd a pointer array with the pointers of the variables and load the array in same application, it work, I can access all variable values.

But when another application load the pointer array, dont work.

How can i pass the correct memory reference to work in 32 and 64bits.
There are some way to do this?

Comment: Under Windows applications are protected from each other and are not allowed to access each other's memory. A question about sharing handles to global memory (i.e. HGLOBAL) has been asked (and answered) previously. Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619430/how-to-share-hglobal-with-another-application

Comment: Don't attempt to share memory. Use some other form of IPC. Sockets, pipes, messages, etc.

Comment: Thanks all,
I think that I found the solution of my problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646202/sharing-data-array-between-two-applications-in-delphi. 
I found this link in the reference link above. I will try to use it.

Comment: Why would you opt for shared memory? I wonder if you have sufficient knowledge of the issues to make a good choice.